# not getting data with $resource, yet the response has body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, client

I've been trying to figure this thing out.
Let me explain the situation:
I'm using $resource with  GET method ,The method returns bool
this look like:

```
            var userTransactionsChanged = $resource(appSettings.serverURL + "/api/Refresh", null,
            {get: {method:'GET' ,headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token }}});

        userTransactionsChanged.get(null).$promise.then(function(rawData) {
            console.log(rawData)
            //
            //if(GetifChangedResultFromData)// I need to get the bool from data
            //  updateAlert();
        });
```

I get 200 OK, And in the response I get true/false(the actual result from API)

The problem is this the data i get in the call back is this:

```
f {$promise: d, $resolved: true}$promise: d$resolved: true__proto__: f
```

Why can't I see the result like I get on other calls?

Is it Client problem or server?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: why `$promise.then` and not just `then` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Well if I just used then it wouldn't work for me. @AvraamMavridis

Comment: But you dont have to `get(null)`, `userTransactionsChanged.then()` should be enough

Comment: Well then I'm not sure what you 're offering.
userTransactionsChanged.then(function(isChanged) {
    var data = isChanged;
    });
Or how?
   userTransactionsChanged.get(null,then(function(isChanged) {
    var data = isChanged;
    
    if(isChanged)
     updateAlert();
   });   
@AvraamMavridis

Comment: This sounds like a cross domain CORS problem where API isn't CORS enabled. Will see response body inspecting network request but browser won't allow access to it due to `same domain policy`. Check for proper response headers